# problems with laravel post and angular post

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.3

i am new in laravel_5.3+Angularjs.i am trying to send some data with angular http post.

```
$scope.close=function(){
         var data1={
          name:$scope.name,
          price:$scope.price
          }

       $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: 'http://localhost/project/public/demo',
                 data: data1
            }).success(function () {
             console.log('true');

            // $location.url("demo");

             })
            .error(function(){
            console.log('false');
             })

            $log.info(data1);
    }
```

and i call a laravel post method demo here is my method

```
Route::post('/demo', function (Request $request) {

    $product=new product;
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->image = 'gjgj';
    $product->active=true;
    $product->save();
    return "saved success fully";

});
```

but i am not getting data in this post method.
as a beginner i am not getting the mistake here.
please help me with some resource.....

Comment: Is `/project/public` the root of your laravel project?

Comment: /project/public yes@WesleyPeeters